# Как создать post запрос через Awesomium?

Tags: c#, winforms, awesomium

Нужен пример отправки post запроса, например, по нажатию кнопки.
Есть url, на который нужно отправлять запрос и допустим поля login и password.
Как это реализовать?

Для примера что я имею ввиду - в WebBrowser это делается так:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("test1.ru/login.php", "_self", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data), "content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, можно при помощи WebClient.UploadString: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient.uploadstring(v=vs.110).aspx